# Android facebook feed dialog doesn't show up

Tags: android, facebook

When I click on the button, the app stopped.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {   
        private  Facebook mFacebook;

Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postToWall();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();     
    }
 public void postToWall() {
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("description", "description about link");
        parameters.putString("picture","link of picture your want add with share post.");
        parameters.putString("link", "Link you want to share");
        parameters.putString("name","Name of link");
        parameters.putString("caption","describe your caption text");

            mFacebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters,new DialogListener() {

                @Override   
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError arg0) {
                }

                public void onError(DialogError arg0) {
                }

                public void onComplete(Bundle arg0) {
                }

                public void onCancel() {
                }
            });
         }
```

StackTrace:

```
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at com.example.imdb.Display.postToWall(Display.java:447)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at com.example.imdb.Display$1.onClick(Display.java:399)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-14 21:26:11.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1021):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also, there is a warning says that The method dialog(Context, String, Bundle, Facebook.DialogListener) from the type Facebook is deprecated. Does this matter? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Where is mFacebook instantiated? Also what is line 447 of your Display code?

Comment: I didn't instantiated it...line 447:mFacebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters,new DialogListener() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mFacebook is probably null. Check it out.

Comment: I just initiate mFacebook. How should I instantiate it?

Comment: `mFacebook = Facebook(yourAppId);`
Check http://developers.facebook.com/android/ for further instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Your mFacebook object is null, you should do `mFacebook = new Facebook ("yourappIDString")`. You must pass an appID to the constructor 
Also, to answer your deprecation question, the Facebook [source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java) states that

> New code should instead use 
>        [Session](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/Session.java) to manage session state, 
>        [Request](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/Request.java) to make API requests,

So if you want to remain compliant, you will need to rewrite some code.